# Find passing trains on image via template matching without having the templates for trains

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I take a picture of a crossing every X seconds, which are then analysed for the state of the crossing, True or False using template matching in opencv2. If the state is True, then I start a session at which point I want to detect if there is a train passing through at any point. The problem is is that I dont have a template for each train that could pass through (4 different companies of passenger trains + freight trains), so there is no template to match my image `I` against. I also have not enough data or time to train a network to recognise any trains.

I am using opencv2, specifically `TM_CCOEFF` algorithm for the crossing's state matching, which works well. How could I detect any passing trains without having each as a sample, possibly even distinguishing passengers from freights?

Here is an example picture that I am taking (I dont have one with a train on):
[image]

Comment: You could check for a closed gate to start a session. Then use background subtraction to determine a train passing

Comment: I'm already doing the first part. With background subtraction, would I compare the image of an empty crossing (as above) against one that contains a train?

Comment: *possibly even distinguishing passengers from freights* — How would you explain the difference to someone who has never seen a train before? Having a computer (or a person) distinguish things it has no model of is impossible.

Comment: @peterxz Indeed, mask out the area inside the gates. Then compare each frame with the one at the start of the session. There are also a functions that can do it for you, like [BackgroundSubtractorMOG2](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d7/d7b/classcv_1_1BackgroundSubtractorMOG2.html). Occlusion of the far gate as Sam Mason suggests could also work and is more efficient.

Comment: it might be easier to look for other features.  e.g. the barriers will presumably come down in roughly the same place and are high contrast difference from the background.  you could also look for occlusion of the far barrier as an proxy for a passing train.  once you've got a few images with actual trains you can start to develop a better classifier

Comment: @J.D. so how is the comparing actually done? `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2.apply()` only takes in one argument, so I'm struggling to understand how it compares it to another picture. Also, Im not recording but take pictures (even once the crossing is down), and this seems to be a video analysis related method?